# Создание своего View в Android

Tags: java, android, listview, view

Заметил что во многих популярных приложений, некоторые View, рисуются заново. Например для ListView, каждый item, это один View, нарисованный с нуля. Телеграм как пример https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/Cells/DialogCell.java

Я так понял, что где много всяких виджетов в одном элементе, то лучше уже отрисовать свой заново? Как это правильно сделать? Может поделитесь статьями? Примерами, и т. п.

Answer (score 1):

Хороший пример [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/), но вообще ищи по запросу custom listview

Comment: Это не то что нужно

Comment: Или интересует именно создание своего компонента? наследника от класса View?

Comment: Создание своего компонента, наследника от класса View

Comment: Тогда вот тут, отличный пример - http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/index.html. Попробуйте повторить эту реализацию, а потом добавьте что нибудь свое